# Как употреблять ни перед глаголами в простом/главном предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, правила

Есть какое-то правило?

## Для повторяющегося ни

Например:

1. Вася ни слушает, ни говорит.
2. Вася ни слушает собеседника, ни говорит по телефону.
3. Вася ни не слушает, ни не говорит.
4. Вася ни не слушает собеседника, ни не говорит по телефону.
5. Вася ни собеседника не слушает, ни по телефону не говорит.

- Неужели тут нельзя обойтись без инверсии с добавлением не?

## Для ни в продолжение предыдущего предложения

Например:

1. Вася не слушает. Ни он говорит.
2. Вася не слушает собеседника. Ни он говорит по телефону.
3. Вася не слушает. Ни он не говорит.
4. Вася не слушает собеседника. Ни он не говорит по телефону.
5. Вася не слушает собеседника. Ни по телефону он не говорит.

Как это сказать по-русски? (аналогично английскому "He isn't listening to the interlocutor, nor is he talking on the phone")

Интересно также, какое правило тут используется, где можно подробней почитать об употреблении.

Comment: @V.V. бывает что говоря первую часть предложения говорящий ещё не знает что будет вторая. поэтому первая звучит как отрицание без и/ни: Вася не слушает собеседника. как теперь добавить ни?

Comment: @V.V. я бы сказал "Вася не слушает собеседника. - пауза, затем добавил: - Ни по телефону (не?) говорит." - но не уверен как правильно

Comment: @V.V. к тому же мне интересен вариант без "сам". Не знаю, может пример неудачный. вот другой: Вася не лежит на диване. Ни на стуле не сидит. - тут уже "сам" неуместно.

Comment: @V.V. да, вот тоже заметил что используется либо как двойной ни-ни, либо не перед глаголами (напр "ни слова не понял"). либо без отрицания ("где бы ни сидел"). думал неужели в одиночку 
 с отрицанием перед глаголом нельзя... странно

Comment: @V.V. а вот вариант с "тем более"? может же отдельно быть? например "я не хотел его покалечить! Ни тем более не хотел я его убить!" или короче: "я не хотел его покалечить! Ни тем более убить!" - можно же так? а если "тем более" убрать - тогда нельзя?

Comment: @V.V. спасибо, прям очень подробно всё расписано. но моих вариантов нету . неужели является безграмотным сказать "я не хотел его покалечить! ни тем более убить!"? - мне кажется вполне правильным... моё чутьё ошибается?